# Setting Custom UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to create a custom `UITextField` like the one shown in image1 but I am only able to create the boxes like in image2. Can anybody help how to perform these in `UITextField`:

1) to set the starting of text after some space (see image1)

2) to set the corners to rounded rectangle shape (see image1)

[image: Image1] 
[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these 2 methods:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> //For accessing and modifying layer property of view

//Rounded corners
[textView.layer setCornerRadius:3.0];

//Putting left margin to the textview (set your desired margins)
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)];
```

Comment: Just a quick note. In order to use the `textView.layer` you will have to do `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the file first.

Comment: setCornerRadius is working but setContentInset is not working since it is not available for uitextfield...

Comment: your original question was for uitextview. if you are certain you want to do it by textfield then i suggest you to add 1-2 white spaces at the beginning (a bit hackish, but should work :)

Comment: I suggest you to use two container views inside the green view then. they provide the rounded corners, background and contain the uitextfields which are positioned to provide the left margin

Answer (score 0):

Add Quartzcore framework to your project

import  QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

and use  `[YourtextView.layer setCornerRadius:2.0];`

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UITextview, use UITextField instead.

Then you can set the UITextBorderStyle as UITextBorderStyleNone, use the rounded rectangle shape image as the background.

Feel free to send me feedback

Answer (score 0):

first Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
UITextField *YourTextViewName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(@"YourSize")];
YourTextViewName.delegate = self;
YourTextViewName.tag = 1;
[self.view addSubview:YourTextViewName];
YourTextViewName.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[[YourTextViewName layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
[[YourTextViewName layer] setBorderWidth:1.0];
[[YourTextViewName layer] setCornerRadius:10];
```

**Another option is :**

Add UITextField on UIImageView...take imageView as roundRect and put UITextField on imageView ,, size of UIImageView is big (not more) then uitextField and give uitextfield backgroung color `clearColor`...such like

```
UIImageView *imgTxtTag = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 150, 265, 30)] ;
    [imgTxtTag setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"SurfaceBtnBG.png"]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imgTxtTag];

UITextField *YourTextViewName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(@"33, 150, 249, 30")];
    YourTextViewName.delegate = self;
YourTextViewName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    YourTextViewName.tag = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:YourTextViewName];
```

Comment: I had used UITextfield.. can u give answer for manual location entry inside uitextfield?